# Code for change UI to Arabic mode in flutter App?

Tags: dart, flutter, arabic, translate

Like iOS code below

Please check this screenshot:
[image: please check this screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried myself but I'd expect the [Directionality Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Directionality-class.html) to do that

```
new Directionality(
    textDirection: language == 'ar' : TextDirection.rtl ? TextDirection.ltr, 
    child: content,
)
```